# How to make a UL submenu height dynamic

Tags: html, css

I have the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g4zLzyqf/

Partial HTML:

```
<div id="navMenuHolder" class="navMenuHolder">
    <nav id="navMenu" class="navMenu">
        <ul>
            <li class="active">
                <a href="index.php">Home</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

As you can see submenu under `Directory` has extra space underneath.

Please help me so that the submenu is dynamic and only expands based on the amount of item in the submenu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are setting child menu height (ul) on hover of parent (li) to 195 px. Change this to auto.

```
.navMenu ul li:hover ul {
    height: auto;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g4zLzyqf/2/

You could also remove this height completely. 

But since you are setting height to 0 in `.navMenu ul ul {` removing the height (not overriding) in hover style `.navMenu ul li:hover ul` would make the child menu height 0.

Remove the height element from both the selectors and that would work just fine.

Comment: Thanks. Which line is it? I can't find it in my code :/

Answer (score 3):

Change to this class the height to auto

```
.navMenu ul li:hover ul{
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. +1 as this also is the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Adjust your margin http://jsfiddle.net/g4zLzyqf/1/

```
.navMenu ul  li:hover ul  {
height: 195px;
margin-top:0px ;
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: That did not help... Height has to be auto!

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge yes i figured it a bit late\

Comment: I +1 because of the margin-top comment which also helped me :)